# I have the p5.js code for a pixelating a preloaded picture. I am trying to make all the rectangles that the picture breaks down into as buttons

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want these buttons to run a specific function. I want this site to allow users to create a colour palette by clicking on the individual rectangles. I want these rectangles to appear highlighted in a certain way to show the they have been selected. here's my code that pixelates the picture, please uncomment some lines to find some bits of trial and error codes:

```
  let img;
//var slider;

preload = () => {
 img = loadImage('collage.jpg');
}
setup = () => {
var canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
canvas.parent('sketch-container');
pixelDensity(1);
//colorMode(HSB, 255);
//slider(min, max, starting value) - from Daniel Shiffman video
//slider = createSlider(0, 255, 127);
//colorMode(HSB, 255);

// Get the webcam feed
//cam = createCapture(VIDEO);
//cam.hide();
//noStroke();
}

//showSelectionBar = () => {
//    rect();
//    //here i am trying to fill this rectangle with the colour values of the selected      rectangle to manipulate
//    fill();


//}

draw = () => {
background(220);
// Display camera image
image(img, 0, 0);
img.resize(windowWidth, 0);
// Load camera image pixels
img.loadPixels();
// Loop through every 50th x and 50th y location
for (let x = 0; x < img.width; x += 50) {
    for (let y = 0; y < img.height; y += 50) {
        // Get the pixel array for each pixel
        // [r,g,b,a]
        let colorFromImage = img.get(x, y);
        // Get the brightness from the rgba array
        fill(colorFromImage);
        //colorMode(HSB, 100);
        // Draw a 50x50 rectangle
        //to make all these rectangels as buttons
        //createButton('');
        //create an array of rectangles
//            rect[];
        rect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}

//    for (let i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
    //to make all these rectangels as buttons
    //array element as button:
    //https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/25738/how-to-create-an-array-of-button-elements-in-p5
//        rect[i] = createButton(i);
      //show selection bar at the bottom
//        rect.mousePressed(showSelectionBar);




//    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what's the problem? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: I am trying to make all the pixelated rectangles as buttons. But when I uncomment all the commented code, and run it, it creates infinite buttons under the where the picture appears. I need the rectangles themselves to be buttons.